# LibGdx Box2D Grounded Sensor

Tags: java, libgdx

I found the tutorial from http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability very useful it recognize when a player grounded  with the ContactListener,i follow all the instructions and all worked really fine but the problem is, when i start moving at the polygon shape MapObject that i made the sensor dont fit properly on the ground so it thinks that i am on the air.! 
http://prntscr.com/7frzj3

Contact Listener

```
public class Contact implements ContactListener{

private boolean playerOnGround=false;

public void beginContact(com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact c) {

    Fixture fa = c.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fb = c.getFixtureB();

    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        playerOnGround = true;

    }
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        playerOnGround = true;
    }



}

@Override
public void endContact(com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact c) {

    Fixture fa = c.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fb = c.getFixtureB();

    if(fa.getUserData() != null && fa.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        playerOnGround = false;
    }
    if(fb.getUserData() != null && fb.getUserData().equals("foot")) {
        playerOnGround = false;
    }

}

public boolean isPlayerOnGround() { return playerOnGround; }

@Override
public void preSolve(com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact contact,Manifold oldManifold) {


}

@Override
public void postSolve(com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact contact,ContactImpulse impulse) {


}

}
```

initializeMapObjectsIntoWorld

```
protected void initializeMapObjectsIntoWorld() {

    MapLayer layer = map.getLayers().get("Collision");
    MapObjects objects = layer.getObjects();

      for(MapObject object : objects) {

            if (object instanceof TextureMapObject) continue;

            Shape shape = null;
            Vector2 vector=null;;


            if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                RectangleMapObject rectangleObj = (RectangleMapObject)object;
                Rectangle rectangle = rectangleObj.getRectangle();
                vector= new Vector2((rectangle.x+rectangle.getWidth()*0.5f)/Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS, (rectangle.y+rectangle.getHeight()*0.5f)/Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS);
                PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
                polygon.setAsBox(rectangle.width * 0.5f / Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS,rectangle.height * 0.5f / Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS);
                shape=polygon;
            }
            else if (object instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
                PolygonMapObject polygonObj = (PolygonMapObject)object;
                PolygonShape polygon = new PolygonShape();
                float[] vertices = polygonObj.getPolygon().getTransformedVertices();
                float[] worldVertices = new float[vertices.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; ++i) {
                    worldVertices[i] = vertices[i] / Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS;
                }
                polygon.set(worldVertices);
                shape=polygon;
                vector=null;

            }
            else if (object instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
                PolylineMapObject polyLineObj = (PolylineMapObject)object;
                Polyline polyLine=polyLineObj.getPolyline();
                vector= new Vector2(polyLineObj.getPolyline().getX(),polyLineObj.getPolyline().getY());
                //vector=scaleToMeters(vector,polyLine.getLength(),polyLineObj.height);
                shape = getPolyline((PolylineMapObject)object);
            }
            else if (object instanceof CircleMapObject) {
                CircleMapObject circleObj = (CircleMapObject)object;
                Circle circle = circleObj.getCircle();
                CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
                circleShape.setRadius(circle.radius / Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS);
                circleShape.setPosition(new Vector2(circle.x / Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS, circle.y / Game.SCALE_PIXELS_ToMETERS));
                vector= new Vector2(circle.x,circle.y);
                shape = circleShape;
            }


            Body body=null;
            if(object.getName().equals("StaticWall")) createWallObject(shape,object.getName(),object,vector); 
            if(body!=null) dynamicBodies.add(body); 



    }


}
```

playerInitializationBody

```
private void initializeEntityIntoWorld() {

      BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
      FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
      PolygonShape boxShape = new PolygonShape();

      bodyDef.position.set(0, 50);
      bodyDef.type=BodyType.DynamicBody;
      bodyDef.fixedRotation=true;
      body = world.createBody(bodyDef);



      boxShape.setAsBox(WIDTH_METER, HEIGHT_METER);
      fixtureDef.shape=boxShape;
      fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = BIT_PLAYER;
      fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = BIT_GROUND;
      fixtureDef.friction=50;
      body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData("player");


     //Sensor
     boxShape.setAsBox(WIDTH_METER/2, HEIGHT_METER/2,new Vector2(0, -HEIGHT_METER),0);
     fixtureDef.shape=boxShape;
     fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = BIT_PLAYER;
     fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = BIT_GROUND;
     fixtureDef.isSensor=true;
     fixtureDef.friction=50;
     body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData("foot");




     boxShape.dispose();

}
```

Comment: Try enabling the Box2dDebugRenderer and see if the fixture shapes have the correct size. They may be just set as too big.

Comment: check the image http://prntscr.com/7frzj3 the sensor is in the right  place